# Easy question: Why is $+ C$ outside the brackets?

Tags: calculus

$$100(-10te^-0.1t + 10 \int e^{-0.1t}dt) = 100(-10te^-0.1t -100e^{-0.1t})+C$$

Why is the $+C$ outside of the brackets if the integration was done inside? I'm looking at my math book and I'm baffled.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please format your question with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Furthermore, it is not clear what is the role of $t$ in your expression, is it the integration variable or a general variable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are multiplying the integral by a constant. The $+C$ is just another constant, it can take any value. So it does not matter if you have $+1000C$ or $-0.00001C$, because they are just constants, and you can denote them as $+C$.

Comment: Yeah. That definitely explains it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Given some constant $C$ if you multiply or add another constant to it then you still end up with a constant. It's often the case that constants will be combined into a single constant rather than leaving them separated so say you have $100C$ then you can define $C' = 100C$ and simply write $f(x) + C'$ instead of $f(x) + 100C$. This practice is common when integrating since the exact value of the constant is largely irrelevant to understanding the solution set for the differential equation you integrated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, $C$ should be inside the brakets and yield a term $100C$ when pulled outside. But writing $100C$ or just $C$ doesn't really make a difference as $C$ is arbitrary. (Provided you don' keep the two instances of $C$ in the same computation !)